# Swift: searchBar still visible with navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

Tags: swift, visible, searchbar, swift4.2

In Swift I'm trying to achieve a hidden `searchBar`, which becomes visible when scrolling,

I'm using this

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

I've tried moving the above code around, but regardless the `searchBar` is visible no matter where this is called in the `ViewController` file.

is there something that could be `overriding` this functionality? 
the only other code in the file where I reference the `searchBar` or `searchController` is the following:

```
if self.searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {...

self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search \(title)"

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredArr = defaultArr.filter {...

func configureSearchController () {

    //Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true 
}

// I call reloadData a few times throughout as well
tableView.reloadData()
```

I'm not sure how any of the above could effect `hideSearchBarWhenScrolling = true`.

[image]

I'm so confused how this is happening, does anyone have any advice?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you please add screenshot of screen?

Comment: I've edited with a gif showing the behaviour

Comment: Could you please try with 20-25 rows in `UITableView`?

Comment: regardless of how many items are in the `UITableView` the `UIsearchBar` is still static and remains visible. I tried with 20-25, 50 etc.

Comment: A label which was "behind" the tableView was causing the issue:

searchBar always visible:
https://imgur.com/lXulqjb

searchBar hidden as intended:
https://imgur.com/4YmlRbK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A label which was "behind" the tableView was causing the issue:

searchBar always visible:

### [image]

searchBar hidden as intended:

[image]